# Need solution on query optimaisation

Tags: apex, query, performance

i have below code where i am doing 2 queries and updating the account record.

```
list<account> parentAccount=new list<account>();
list<account> ChildAccount=new list<account>();
parentAccount = [select id from Account where CSRId__C=:Csrnum LIMIT 1];
if(parentAccount.size()>0){
    acc.parentid=parentAccount.get(0).id;
}
else{
    "Error-parentaccount not found"
}
ChildAccount= [select id from Account where customer__c=:customer LIMIT 1];          
if(ChildAccount.size()>0){
    accountRec.ChildAccountId__c=ChildAccount.get(0).id;
}
else
  "Error-Child account not found"
}
```

I am using 2 soql queries on account 1 for finding account by Csrnum which is number i will provide  and 2 for finding account by customer which is again different number. Please suggest.

We can do like this

```
List<account> accounts = [select id from Account where CSRId__C=:Csrnum or customer__c=:customer LIMIT 2];
if(accounts.size() == 2) {
    Account parentAccount;
    Account childAccount;
    for(Account a : accounts) {
        if(a.CSRId__C == Csrnum) {
           acc.parentid= a.id;
        } else{
            else{
                "Error-parent account not found"
    }
    if(a.customer__c == customer) {
        acc.ChildAccountId__c= a.id;
    } 
    else{
        "Error-child account not found"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that `CSRID__c` is only populated for Parent account and `customer__c` is only populated for child accounts, you can do following. Otherwise you'll have to run two queries to get parent and child accounts separately.

```
List<account> accounts = [select id from Account where CSRId__C=:Csrnum or customer__c=:customer LIMIT 2];
if(accounts.size() == 2) {
    Account parentAccount;
    Account childAccount;
    for(Account a : accounts) {
        if(a.CSRId__C == Csrnum) {
            parentAccount = a;
        } 
        if(a.customer__c == customer) {
            childAccount = a;
        } 
    }

    if(parentAccount != null){
        acc.parentid=parentAccount.get(0).id;
    }
    else{
        "Error-parentaccount not found"
    }

    if(ChildAccount != null){
        accountRec.ChildAccountId__c=ChildAccount.get(0).id;
    }
    else{
        "Error-Child account not found"
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of Posting Code can you Please explain it

Comment: How you can guarantee that 2 records are each type with that SOQL query? It could be possible that 2 records return satisfying `CSRId__C=:Csrnum` itself

Comment: @SantanuBoral Yes you are correct!. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two separate conditions in the WHERE condition and also limiting the record to 1, so 2 separate queries are fine this scenario.

Comment: What about usage of set @Santhanu. we will collect Csrnum ,customer in one set. write single query and check containskey .will it work?

Comment: Since you are limiting 1 record for each Csrnum and customer then one query will not solve your purpose. Even you put LIMIT 2, it will not return one record for each type. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Sorry Not in One set :) different sets (In case of many records)...He specified LIMIT 1..It makes sense

Comment: can you please tell m how we can use set here.If u can give sample code then it would be good to me

Comment: As I mentioned you earlier, you need to separate SOQL queries